# hive join failed mr.MapredLocalTask

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I am new to HIVE and HADOOP , here i am trying to join two sample  tables in hive where the tables do not have any primary foreign key relationship just for practicing    :-
     the tables are as follows

```
  Employees table:-
                id   name    gender   salary  departmentid      

                 1    mark      male    3333    1
                 2    Steve     male    5464    3
                 3    Ben       male    3873    2
                 4    bender    male    9298    1
                 5    fender    male    654     2

 departments table:-
             id    name     location

             1     IT        NEW YORK
             2     HR        LONDON
             3     PAYROLL   SYDNEY  

hive>  select employees.name as employee_name, departments.name as department_name
    >  from employees         
    >  join departments on departments.id = employees.departmentid;
```

RESULT :-

> Query ID =
>   cloudera_20170911030505_93378edb-f8b8-45d0-9141-3fe065211f3d
>               Total jobs = 1
>               FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

since i am new to hive from SQL suggest me how to solve this error ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the entire stack trace for better clarity.

Comment: Query ID = cloudera_20170911041010_375af566-cc17-4649-b992-7a8a10685316
Total jobs = 1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

Comment: A similar issue has been raised.Check this link:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/Hue-FAILED-Execution-Error-return-code-1-from-org-apache-hadoop/td-p/36256.

Comment: Surprised to see only a 2 line Error.Check if you can get the complete stack trace.That will help in pointing out the exact root cause.

Comment: community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/….                              <-- that raised  issue is with missing jar  ... i have shared complete stack trace

Answer (score 1):

set hive.auto.convert.join=false; Fixed the issue in my case..

Answer (score 0):

Query:

select employees.name as employee_name, departments.name as department_name
from employees T1
join departments T2 on T1.departmentid=T2.id;

Hive up to version 0.13 does not support Primary key concepts. This has been introduced in the later releases on hive.
So, we just need to take care is that the columns are present, in case of duplicates in the columns, it will create multiple records.
If you want to have some other use cases, you can try using Left Outer Join, Right Outer join, Full join. Be careful while using cross joins.

If the error still persists, please send more details about the table schema that you have used. You can use show create table db_name.table_name to view your complete schema.